# webkit-transition not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am new CSS animations.I am doing transition on a block when I hover on it. But when I hover on it nothing happens.

```
    <!--HTML-->
    <div class="pageTwo">
  <div class="block-works">
    <p class="work">We at Good Tree production watch movies at full time.Watching movies at 24 X 7 is our duties and reviewing them is our homework </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.block-works{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
      opacity: 0.8;
      padding-right: auto;
      display:block;
    width:90%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    transition: width 2s
}
.blockworks:hover{
  width:90%;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
```

Comment: I believe your `.blockworks:hover` selector should actually be written `.block-works:hover` with a dash in between.

Answer (score 1):

Check this code hope it helps.

```
#HTML

    <div class="pageTwo">
      <div class="block-works">
        <p class="work">We at Good Tree production watch movies at full time.Watching movies at 24 X 7 is our duties and reviewing them is our homework </p>
      </div>
     </div>

#CSS
    .block-works{
        position:relative;
        background-color: black;
          opacity: 0.8;
          padding-right: auto;
          display:block;
        width:90%;
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-bottom:100px;
        margin-left: 5%;
        margin-right: 5%;
        border-radius: 7px;
        height: 200px;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s;
        transition: width 2s
    }
    .block-works:hover{
      width:100px;
      transition-delay: 0.6s;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have commented what i have changed in css snippet

```css
.block-works{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: black;
      opacity: 0.8;
      padding-right: auto;
      display:block;
    width:40%; /* initial width changed to show animation */
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    border-radius: 7px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: width 2s
}
.block-works:hover{ /* name of class changed */
  width:90%;
  transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--HTML-->
    <div class="pageTwo">
  <div class="block-works">
    <p class="work">We at Good Tree production watch movies at full time.Watching movies at 24 X 7 is our duties and reviewing them is our homework </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```